# Сортировать таблицу по нажатии кнопки

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

Имеется следующее: данные в таблице появляются из БД `SQLite`. Требуется при нажатии на кнопку "по названию" сортировать столбец "Название товара" по возрастанию или убыванию.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код контроллера следующий

```
package com.lengu.information.systems.lb.two.controller;



public class ProductController {
    @FXML
    public Button nazvButton;
    @FXML
    private Label message = new Label();

    @FXML
    private TextField fieldMinPrice = new TextField ();

    @FXML
    private TextField fieldMaxPrice = new TextField ();

    @FXML
    private TextField fieldMinDiscount = new TextField();

    @FXML
    private TextField fieldMaxDiscount = new TextField();

    @FXML
    private TextField fieldMinBatchQuantity = new TextField();

    @FXML
    private TextField fieldMaxBatchQuantity = new TextField();

    @FXML
    private TableView<Product> productTableView;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, String> nameProduct;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, Double> priceProduct;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, Integer> batchQuantityProduct;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, Integer> numberProducts;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Product, Double> discountProduct;


    private ObservableList<Product> masterData;

    private ProductService productService;
    private List<Product> productList;
    private Product activeProduct;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        productService = new ProductService();
        loadData();
        initFirstValues();
        initTable();
    }


    private void loadData(){
        try {
            productList = productService.getAll();
            activeProduct = productList.get(0);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initTable(){
        masterData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        masterData.addAll(productList);
        nameProduct.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("name"));
        priceProduct.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Double>("price"));
        numberProducts.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Integer>("number"));
        discountProduct.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Double>("discount"));
        batchQuantityProduct.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Integer>("batchQuantity"));
        productTableView.setItems(masterData);

        FilterSupport.addFilter(nameProduct);
    }

    private void initFirstValues(){
        Double minDiscount = productList.get(0).getDiscount();
        Double maxDiscount = 0.0;

        Integer minBatchQuantity = productList.get(0).getBatchQuantity();
        Integer maxBatchQuantity = 0;

        Double minPrice = productList.get(0).getPrice();
        Double maxPrice = 0.0;

        for (Product product : productList){
            if (product.getDiscount() < minDiscount)
                minDiscount = product.getDiscount();
            if (product.getDiscount() > maxDiscount)
                maxDiscount = product.getDiscount();

            if (product.getBatchQuantity() < minBatchQuantity)
                minBatchQuantity = product.getBatchQuantity();
            if (product.getBatchQuantity() > maxBatchQuantity)
                maxBatchQuantity = product.getBatchQuantity();

            if (product.getPrice() < minPrice)
                minPrice = product.getPrice();
            if (product.getPrice() > maxPrice)
                maxPrice = product.getPrice();
        }

        fieldMinDiscount.setText(minDiscount.toString());
        fieldMaxDiscount.setText(maxDiscount.toString());

        fieldMinBatchQuantity.setText(minBatchQuantity.toString());
        fieldMaxBatchQuantity.setText(maxBatchQuantity.toString());

        fieldMinPrice.setText(minPrice.toString());
        fieldMaxPrice.setText(maxPrice.toString());
    }

    @FXML
    public void filtred(){
        loadData();
        message.setText("");
        try {
            Double minDiscount = Double.valueOf(fieldMinDiscount.getText());
            Double maxDiscount = Double.valueOf(fieldMaxDiscount.getText());

            Integer minBatchQuantity = Integer.valueOf(fieldMinBatchQuantity.getText());
            Integer maxBatchQuantity = Integer.valueOf(fieldMaxBatchQuantity.getText());

            Double minPrice = Double.valueOf(fieldMinPrice.getText());
            Double maxPrice = Double.valueOf(fieldMaxPrice.getText());

            List<Product> filtredProductList = new ArrayList<Product>();
            for (Product product : productList) {
                if (product.getDiscount() >= minDiscount && product.getDiscount() <= maxDiscount)
                    if (product.getBatchQuantity() >= minBatchQuantity && product.getBatchQuantity() <= maxBatchQuantity)
                        if (product.getPrice() >= minPrice && product.getPrice() <= maxPrice)
                            filtredProductList.add(product);
            }

            productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
            productList = filtredProductList;
            initTable();
        } catch (Exception e){
            message.setText("Ошибка. Значения фильтров указаны не верно!");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void removeFiltred(){
        message.setText("");
        initialize();
    }

    @FXML
    public void openEntry(){
        openWindow("Просмотр товара", "/jfx/view_product.fxml");
    }

    private void openWindow(String title, String path) {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = null;
        try {
            root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ProductDetailsController productDetailsController = loader.getController();
        productDetailsController.setActiveProduct(productTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void onSetNazv(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@FXML
public void onSetNazv() {
    //по возрастанию
    nameProduct.setSortType( TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING );
    //по убыванию
    //nameProduct.setSortType( TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING );
    productTableView.getSortOrder().setAll( nameProduct );
}
```

Comment: Thanks!your answer was informative for me and so helpful